# How to make git log show file paths relative to current directory?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-difftool

The current Git-based project that I am working on, I am generally always in a sub-directory.

Below is the output when I run the command `git log --name-only` from a sub-directory of the root of the repository.

```
commit 678bd5ba6fc5474c4c61406768bf6cba5937c5d1
Author: thegreendroid
Date:   Mon Mar 27 09:36:24 2017 +1300

    Commit message

 child_dir1_from_root/file1                     |  184 +--
 child_dir2_from_root/file2                     |    2 +-
```

How do I instead get `git log` to output something like below instead? This makes diffing the files listed really easy, by just copying the file path and running `git diff HEAD~ {copied_file_path}` rather than having to modify the file path manually and then run the command.

```
commit 678bd5ba6fc5474c4c61406768bf6cba5937c5d1
Author: thegreendroid
Date:   Mon Mar 27 09:36:24 2017 +1300

    Commit message

 file1                                          |  184 +--
 ../child_dir2_from_root/file2                  |    2 +-
```

I have looked at the `git log` documentation, but nothing stood out. I can write a script to do this, but I was curious whether Git has a built-in way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use the paths in the output of `git log --name-only`, add the option `--git-dir` to `git diff`.

```
git --git-dir="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/.git diff HEAD~ child_dir1_from_root/file1
```

For easy use, make an alias in the config.

```
[alias]
        mdiff = "! git --git-dir=\"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)\"/.git diff"
```

`git mdiff HEAD~ child_dir1_from_root/file1` now can work as long as the current directory belongs to the working tree.

Comment: Beautiful! The alias method works fine, but directly running it on the command line throws an error (fatal: Not a git repository: '$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git').

Answer (score 2):

You can add up the [--relative='PATH'](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---relativeltpathgt) to the subdirectory you want.

Comment: Well this appears to exclude changes apart from the specified directory, which is not what I want.